# ActiveRecord migrations: monitor for external dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, github

Is there any tool or cloud service that can monitor Ruby on Rails projects hosted on GitHub for one of the ActiveRecord migration's worst practices: using calls to methods and classes declared somewhere in the project, but external to the migration itself?

The problem: 
migration M uses some methods from class C, class gets updated at some point of time, method's behavior changed, migration gets broken and does not run anymore.

Code Climate is almost perfect, 
but can not check bad practices in migrations now.

**Any ideas?**

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's any worse for a migration to depend on a particular class/method than for any other code to do so ... which is necessary to get any value from it.

Comment: The problem here is not that the migration depends on code in another class, e.g. a model (which is a common and reasonable practice). The problem is that the model's external API, which other classes like your migration depend on, was not covered by tests. If it had been covered by tests, they would have failed when the model's API unexpectedly changed, and the person making the change would have realized that other classes depends on it and they need to consider that when making changes.

Comment: Thanks, Mori & Jordan. Models are covered by tests. The problem is person who modifies model could change a test first and then modify a model to pass new test conditions. And nobody will pay attention to migration... ( Maybe there's some way to test migrations (to get test fail before app deployment fails)?